# SQL and Crystal Reports in ADO.NET

Tags: crystal-reports

I've created crystal reports using ADO.NET datasets, the reports are working just fine but now my question is:.

How do I make my report to get data from multiple tables because I tried using INNER JOIN method and it didn't work,it displayed nothing....

So can someone give me an idea on how to make crystal report to get data from multiple tables using VB.NET? And tell me the purpose of "SQL Expression" in Crystal Reports.

Please, Thank You.

Comment: Why don't you post your code so we've got something to look at.

Comment: use left join,right join, union, or any this could be solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.doc.crdesigner/reportdesigner/crconsqlexpressions.htm) to get you started on the purpose of SQL Expression Fields. And without any code for your table joins nobody will be able to help you out.

EDIT:

Instead of `where customers.cust_id = '"& txtcustnr.text & "'"` try `where customers.cust_id = txtcustnr.text`
I don't know what data is in "txtcustnr.text", but if you you want the data from txtcustnr.text to be the same as customers.cust_id, then try the above WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

Con.close
Con.open
Query = "select customers.cust_id,customers.cust_fname,customers.cust_lname,invoices.inv_id,invoices.inv_date from customers Inner Join Invoices ON customers.cust_id = invoices.cust_id where customers.cust_id = '"& txtcustnr.text & "'"

Con.close